# Query with data that it may not be exist

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables

table `Customer`

- cus_id
- cus_name

table Buying

- buy_id,
- cus_id(FK to Customer),
- price

The result that I want

```
cus_id, cus_name, buy_id, price
```

but in case some customers don't have buy_id. How can I query like this.

```
cus_id, cus_name, null, null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to display all customer even if he hasn't buy anything yet.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.buy_id, b.price
FROM    customer a
        LEFT JOIN buying b
            ON a.cus_id = b.cus_id
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thank you.
I also want to know how to make grey background in the post.

Comment: select the code you want, then on the editor tools click `{ }`

Comment: It is possible to change word null to different word.

Comment: @aratn0n yes, use `COALESCE`, eg `COALESCE(columnName, 'xx')` if the value of the column is null, it will display `xx`. [MySQL COALESCE (*click here*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

BY USING `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select 
c.cus_id, 
cus_name, 
buy_id, 
price
from 
Customers c
LEFT JOIN Buying b on (c.cus_id=b.cus_id)
```